# Global variable scope issue

Tags: vb.net, asp.net

I have a vb.net (I am new to vb.net) site that is supporting 10 languages and 30 or 40 countries. I have it architected so that all the files that contain content are located in a inc folder located at root and are called into my container files via Response.WriteFile. My plan is to make the paths the the container files dynamic and set them in a file in the country folders.

My question is what type of files should I use and and how would I use them? Thanks

Hierarchy example
/inc/content.aspx (when pulled into the us folder file need to reference the variables set in config file at the /us/ level)

/us/index.aspx (container file calling files in inc folder with Response.WriteFile)
/us/configFile (file will contain variables that set paths within all files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net has a fairly well thought out way of doing [Globalization or Internationlization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx) that is built into the framework.

Do yourself a favor and work with the framework instead of going through the pain of writing this from scratch.